# Python - why do recursive calls increment a variable even though there is no return value?

Tags: python

Why does this work?

This is a recursive function to multiply positive numbers by addition.

```
def multiplication(num1, num2):
  if num1 == 0 or num2 == 0:
    return 0
  print(num1, " ", num2)
  if num1 == 1:
    return num2
  total = num2 + multiplication(num1-1, num2)
  return total
```

I understand the the function will call itself num1 - 1 times. What I don't understand is why the variable total is incremented by the value of num2 each time the function returns. The last time the function is called it returns num2 (first off the call stack) makes sense but the other calls return nothing and the value of num2 is never changed. It seems like total should be set to None not += num2.

Thanks

Comment: `but the other calls return nothing` What do you mean? They return `total`.

Comment: why do you think the other calls dont return anything? theres a return `total`.

Comment: I guess that is what I don't understand. the recursive call total = "some code" looks like an assignment. I guess I'm having trouble with the syntax.

Comment: Ah i see. Well, first things first, youre absolutely correct that total="some code" looks like assignment, because IT IS. However, on the right hand side, there is a function that is being called, and must be evaluated before this total gets a value assigned. You can think of it like a "evaluation" of an answer coming from the function. Each evaluation calls the function (which happens to be the same function in this code) onto a lower level stack, and just waits for the completion of evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dry run of your code for `multiplication(3, 10)` will look like this.

```
     Num1 Num2 total  Return

1st:   3   10

2nd:   2   10

3rd:   1   10          10(returned to the 2nd)

2nd:   2   10    20    20(returned to the 1st)

1st:   3   10    20    30(returned to the output)
```

As you can see from the dry run that the value of `Num2` is never changed.

Comment: Thank you, I thinking about what the calls produced on the way to the base case, not what happens on the return trip.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new here.